# Text To Speech not reading some words on Android 14

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm experiencing an unusual behavior with the Text-to-Speech (TTS) functionality on my Xiaomi Mi 10 running Android 14. The TTS engine skips reading certain words, even though it was working fine initially. However, after some time, it started omitting words. Interestingly, when I switch to Locale.UK, it reads everything correctly.

To further investigate, I tested the same code on a different phone, a Redmi Note 11 running Android 13, and it worked flawlessly as well.

```
private var textToSpeech: TextToSpeech? = null

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        readText("Test")
        delay(3000)
        readText("2")
        readSilentGap(300)
        readText("1") // not reading with Locale.US
        readText("1")
        readSilentGap(300)
        readText("3")
        readSilentGap(100)
        readText("end") // not reading with Locale.US
    }
}

private fun readText(text: String, queueParam: Int = TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD) {
    if (textToSpeech == null) {
        textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(App.instance) { status ->
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                textToSpeech?.language = Locale.US
                textToSpeech?.setSpeechRate(1.0f)
                textToSpeech?.speak(text, queueParam, null, text)
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "readText init error: $status")
            }
        }
    } else {
        textToSpeech?.speak(text, queueParam, null, text)
    }
}

private fun readSilentGap(durationInMillis: Long) {
    textToSpeech?.playSilentUtterance(durationInMillis, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null)
}
```

**Update**

I tried to decrease speech rate, and it did helped me.
`textToSpeech?.setSpeechRate(0.9f)`